# Making RadioButtonGroup unclickable for some period

Tags: android

I have a radio button group and I want to make the radio buttons to be clickable after a few seconds when one of them is clicked. I tried to set the radioButtonGroup disabled with setEnable(false) and unclickable with setClickable(false) but neither of them worked. How can I achieve this?

```
private boolean isFastMenuItemChange(long time)
{
    long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long timeSpace = curTime - lastClickTime;
    if (0 < timeSpace && timeSpace < time) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view){

if(isFastMenuItemChange(2000))
 {
   mBottomRadioGroup.setEnabled(false);
   mBottomRadioGroup.setClickable(false);
   mBottomRadioGroup.setFocusable(false);
   mBottomRadioGroup.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
   return;
 }
    lastClickTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mBottomRadioGroup.setEnabled(true);
    mBottomRadioGroup.setClickable(true);
    mBottomRadioGroup.setFocusable(true);
    mBottomRadioGroup.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

//And so on..
}
```

Comment: Just set the RadioGroup as disabled.

Comment: Could you show us the code that you tried? Perhaps you were just doing a small thing incorrectly

Comment: set unable and unclickable to all child radio of radiogroup.

Comment: I added my code. It seems to be not doing anything on the radio buttons. I  can disable items individually, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
setFocusable(false);
setClickable(false);
```

Comment: Please provide details to your answer

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a method for disabling all elements in the RadioButtonGroup one one by one and then re-enabling them after a desired seconds. I used this void method on my onRadioButtonClick method. Here is my solution

```
private void radioButtonDisabler(){

 for(int i = 0; i < mBottomRadioGroup.getChildCount(); i++){
        mBottomRadioGroup.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(false);
    }
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < mBottomRadioGroup.getChildCount(); i++){
                mBottomRadioGroup.getChildAt(i).setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }, 1000); //Re-enable after each one after desired time.
}
```